# Point Color in R

Tags: r, regression

I have some data, one of whose vectors is gender where gender equals 1 for female and 0 for male.

Assume "reg" is my linear model.

When I do `plot(studres(reg)~reg$fitted)` it gives me the plot I want, but I would like it to color the male errors blue. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm still a rookie at R, so I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plot(reg$fitted, studres(reg), col = dat$gender)`

Assuming data is of the form:

```
> dat
   y  x gender
1  0  0 female
2 10  5 female
3 15 10   male
4 20 15 female
5 24 20   male
6 11 25   male
7 30 30 female
8 34 35   male
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Underminer

Answer (score 4):

Use the `col` option.

Also, try `?plot` to get some working examples.

```
set.seed(12)

mydata <- data.frame(
x = rnorm(50),
y = rnorm(50),
male = sample(c(0,1), 50, replace=T)
)

pointCol <- vector()
pointCol[mydata$male==1] <- "blue"
```

pointCol[mydata$male==0] <- "red"

```
plot(mydata$x,mydata$y,col=pointCol,pch=16)

legend("topright", pch=16, c("male","female"), col=c("blue", "red"), title = 
"Keys")
```

[image]